# trig functions returning incorrect values

Tags: c++

I've been trying to write a program that uses the trig functions in `cmath`, `sin()` and `cos()` in particular.
I understand that these functions use radians so I added `* pi / 180` however the program still displays incorrect numbers. Here is some code.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    using namespace std;

    const double pi = 3.1415926;

    int main()
    {
        int x = 0;
        double d;
        for(int forl=0;forl < 10;forl++)
        {
           d = sin(50 / pi * 180);
           cout << d << endl;
           x += 5;
        }
        cin >> x;
        return 0;
    }
```

WHy does this code display incorrect numbers?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?  "Incorrect numbers" is not very helpful.

Comment: sin(50°) = sin(50 * pi / 180) in radians.

Comment: Seems more like a question about math: "What in the following code did I mess up so that the standard library is giving me an unexpected answer?"

Comment: you say you added `* pi / 180` but you actually added `/ pi * 180`... there's a difference. EDIT: Also, use `M_PI` instead of defining `double pi = ...`. It has more digits than your approximation.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: `M_PI` is non-standard. `4 * atan(0.0)` may be better.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Or rather, 4 * atan( 1.0 )

Comment: @SeaBass: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: You're not likely to get "correct" answers anyway. Mathematically, sin(π) is zero, but passing the nearest floating-point approximation of π to the `sin` function, is going to give you a close floating-point approximation of something that's not quite zero. I get about `1.22465e-16`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sin(50 / pi * 180);
```

uses the exact same angle every time through the loop, so you'll print sin(50°) ten times.  Perhaps you meant

```
sin(x * pi / 180.0);
```

Comment: @tmpearce: Most likely, yes